# How to print byte array data to Zebra printer?

Tags: java, zebra-printers

I want to print a PDF file to [Zebra printer](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/printers/desktop.html) using a Java application. I have generated a PDF using [Jasper reports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/reporting-software) with 2D bar codes. If I am performing manual print to Zebra printer it's printing that PDF file but once I am trying to print the same pdf file  using the Java application, the job is submitting to printer but print is not happening.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobAdapter;
import javax.print.event.PrintJobEvent;

public class ZebraPrintUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        byte[] content = convertFileToBytes("D://old files/test123.pdf");
        print(content, "ZDesigner GX420t");
    }

    private static byte[] convertFileToBytes(String absoluteFilePath) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(absoluteFilePath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        try {
            for (int readNum;
            (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); // no doubt here is 0
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }

        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        return bytes;
    }

    private static boolean print(byte[] byteArray, String reqPrinterId)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        boolean isPrintedSuccessfully = false;
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
        flavor, null);

        if (services.length > 0) {
            PrintService myService = null;

            for (PrintService service: services) {
                if (service.getName().contains(reqPrinterId)) {
                    myService = service;
                    break;
                }
            }

            DocPrintJob printJob = myService.createPrintJob();
            JobCompleteMonitor monitor = new JobCompleteMonitor();
            printJob.addPrintJobListener(monitor);
            Doc document = new SimpleDoc(byteArray, flavor, null);

            try {
                printJob.print(document, null);
                monitor.waitForJobCompletion();
                System.out.println("-------------------- Print Completed " + monitor.completed);

                isPrintedSuccessfully = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return isPrintedSuccessfully;
    }

    private static class JobCompleteMonitor extends PrintJobAdapter {
        private boolean completed = false;

        @Override
        public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        @Override
        public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
            signalCompletion();
        }

        private void signalCompletion() {
            synchronized(JobCompleteMonitor.this) {
                completed = true;
                JobCompleteMonitor.this.notify();
            }
        }

        public synchronized void waitForJobCompletion() {
            try {
                while (!completed) {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show ur src code mate

Comment: How did you perform a manual print - `copy /b x,pdf prn:`? Normally one leaves it to adobe to print the pdf.

Comment: Manual print means open that pdf file and click on print button select the zebra printer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code work as charm, I tried your code with " RICOH MP C306Z" printer n it is working fine. So much thanks my friend MALL. One thing I want to mention here that I don't know what is Zebra printer but this code work for me in " RICOH MP C306Z" printer.

Answer (score 0):

For [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) integration:

```
File file = ...
if (Desktop.isDesktopAvailable()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().print(file);
}
```

Comment: After reading that pdf file i want to perform silent printing.First i will check whether printer is attached  or not to that machine where my java program is running then i will send this document to that printer.

Answer (score 0):

I used Pramod code but before that I have to pass my printer id that is name of printer. I am getting byte array from my db.

```
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;

try {

            PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            pras.add(new Copies(1));
            PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);

            if (pss.length == 0)
                throw new RuntimeException("No printer services available.");

            //You have to check which printer you want to print.
            PrintService ps = pss[1];

            logger.info("Printing to " + ps);

            //Here I am calling Pramod method.
            boolean result = PrintPDF.print(byteArray, ps.getName());
            logger.info("result " + result);

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

This is not answer, this code will call Pramod method which is precise solution.
Thanks